# how to make http in img url to https

Tags: wordpress, ssl, nginx, https, woocommerce

I have implemented https on my website.
I have the following html code on multiple pages on my webshop in the product description:

```
<img src="http://www.example.com/img.png" >
```

It's in woocommerce, but I don't know how I can replace this in my database (in phpmyadmin), so I want to do a nginx rewrite to https.
the following nginx config:

```
... omited...


         if ($ssl_protocol = "") {
       rewrite ^   https://www.example.com$request_uri? permanent;
    }
        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }


... omited...
```

How can I make the src="http://..." end up in an ssl url so I get rid of the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not something you can really fix in nginx. The redirect itself would be served over HTTP and blocked by the browser before being loaded for the same reasons.

Comment: Indeed, thanks for the reply. I was looking in the wrong direction. Just had to download my database, edit it with notepad and replace the old database with the edited one, and problem solved.
Nginx would make things complicated and would blocked like you said, or end up in a redirection loop.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I find out I could open the database with notepad, and do a replace all with the right url. I was looking it to far. An nginx solution would be to complicated + not efficient.